# Can i easily use EJB3 Remote with a RAD framework?

Tags: java, grails, jakarta-ee, groovy, ejb-3.0

I'm planning to make a webapp and just wonder if someone ever tried to use remote EJBs with a RAD framework like Grails, Play... was it easy?

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: I don't think that it should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning **Grails**, it is possible and easy to use remote **EJB 2.1**. So considering that EJB 3 is easier than 2.1, I suppose that you could give it a try with some prototype project.

See this [article](http://dave-klein.blogspot.com/2008/03/integrating-grails-with-ejb-2.html) for clarification. This [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/daveklein/grails-integration-strategies) is also given you integration strategies with EJB 2 and 3

P.S: I didn't try myself since I have no need of it

Comment: Thank you, it seems nice.

Just wonder, is it possible to use Local EJB's instead of Remote to avoid the serialization of parameters?

Comment: I suppose yes but again I didn't try. Please, if you test it, share your results with the community.

Comment: Anyway i think i've read something like Remote ejb's, in the same ear file, doesn't serialize the arguments so performances are the same as if the interface was Local. But not sure...

Comment: @SebastienLorber this seems to be very old question but I am wondering were you able to get it working ?
It will be great if you provide the sample code that you used in the Service/controller class to interact with EJB